# Find out where a helper is being loaded in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller, helper

I am having a project, that contains several Controllers, Views and Helpers (The original developer, from whom I overtook the job, didn't bother to use Models).
In one of the Controllers (Iframes.php), there is (of course) a function __construct(), an index() and a function called view().
In the construct, there is a $this->load->helper('iframes');
No other helpers are being loaded.

The website is being accessed by address https://website.ext/iframes/view/1234567890

In the iframes_helper.php, there is no reference to another helper file soever.
But the iframes_helper.php is calling a function called get_loans(). That function only exists in one file: loans_helper.php

There are OTHER Controllers that load the loans_helper.php (by its normal way).

If I rename the loans_helper.php (to loans_helper.php1), the system won't load, stating a file is missing. It doesn't tell me WHERE there is being referred to the missing file.

I've searched through all the files for

```
load->helper('loans')
```

even for

```
load->helper('loans
```

and

```
('loans')
```

but there is nowhere a referral to the loans_helper file. At least not in Controllers that are being used in the Iframes Controller or files belonging to it.

But the function get_loans is still accessible. How can this be? Or rather: how do I find out where the helper is being loaded?

Albert

Please tell me, if I need to add some code.

Answer (score 2):

You should also search for variants of 'loan' using double quotes, `"loan`, since that's also valid.

At the top of the `loans_helper.php` file, add `debug_print_backtrace(); die;`, which will output some useful information about the execution path. Note that if you're testing in a browser, that you should view the source of the page, to get a more usable format. From the backtrace you'll be able to determine how the file is being included (i.e. via CI's loader system, or directly via `include` or `require`).

Here's [PHP's documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php) on `debug_print_backtrace()`.

Lastly, here are a couple other thoughts on where such a file could be included:

- Within CI's `autoload.php` config file. There's an item for autoloading helper files.
- If Composer exists in the project, check the composer.json file for a reference to the file.
- Technically CI's helper files don't need to be included via CI's loader, so the file might be manually included in using `include` or `require`.

Comment: You were totally right! It was in the autoload.php!